# Facebook API suddenly empty leads result

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have integrated Facebook API to get lead forms & leads, but few days ago leads service not working while lead form service still working.

Lead forms service (works fine and return lead count)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<form_id>?fields=id,leads_count&access_token=<token>
```

Leads service (Not working getting empty result)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<form_id>/leads?access_token=<token>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: I have same problem